# how can I control cassandra replication?

Tags: replication, cassandra, cluster-computing

When I am making an Insert in a specified keyspace, I wants that the data is stored only in a specified node (or node list). The information contains in the insert, may be confidential and should not be distributed on any nodes.
I first thought about implementing my own `AbstractReplicationStrategy`, but it seams that the first node choose depends on the Token (selected by the partitioner) and not the implemented strategy.
How can I be sure the the information contains in a keyspace only comes where I allow this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that it is possible to do what you are asking. Cassandra actively tries to maintain a certain number of replicas of each piece of data- even if you managed to force only a single node to store your insert (which is fairly straighforward), you'd have no control over which node that was (as you found, this is controlled by the partitioner), and if the node went down your data would be lost.

The short answer is that controlling replication is not the way to achieve data security- you should use proper security techniques such as encryption, segregated networks, controlled access, etc.